# Slightly different answer second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am writing this because I am stuck on a certain question on a homework I have to turn in. I am supposed to solve it using variation of parameters as opposed to using undetermined coefficients, which would make it easier in my opinion. Anyway, all online solution checkers like symbolab and wolfram alpha say the answer is *slightly* different to what I got. [image: This is my work]

However, all of the online solutions say the correct answer is [image: This.]

Is my work a correct solution or is that extra $e^{-x}$ wrong?

Comment: since $c_2$ is arbitrary, can you not make it $c_2' = c_2+1$?

Comment: @RahulMadhavan that would mean I can also make it c2 - 1 and cancel them out, giving me the other answer right? I guess that would mean I did it correctly

Comment: not sure about correct, but it would mean you match wolfram alpha :-)